# GoDaddy .htaccess for a subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been developing a website, and my .htaccess for a subdomain doesn't seem to be working right.

The .htaccess file in my subdomain.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+home\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ home.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I goto my subdomain, I can get to me index.php, but when I goto my home.php or /home etc it doesn't seem to work, and redirects to my 404 page (which has been defined in my root directory.

My Root Directories .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.ca/error?id=404
ErrorDocument 403 http://example.ca/error?id=403
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.ca/error?id=500

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.james-emerson\.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://james-emerson.ca/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
```

My Root looks something like:

```
/
 - content/
 - include/
 - sites/
   - external/
     - sbfg/ (subdomains subdirectory)
       - content/
       - include/
       - .htaccess
       - index.php
       - home.php
     - ...etc...

 - .htaccess
 - index.php
 - ...etc...
```

If you can help, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to fix the problem on my own, with help from @anubhava.

The .htaccess file that @anubhava gave me:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sbfg//home\.php\?page=([^\s&]*)[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /sbfg/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /sbfg/home.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Wasn't working correctly because my server was going to the url `sites/external/sbfg/sbfg/home.php` rather then `sites/home/sbfg/home.php`. It was until I removed the 404 document code from my roots .htaccess file, that I notices the error.

I than updated my code to:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /home\.php\?page=([^\s&]*)[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /home.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then added some of the code to my root directories .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 http://james-emerson.ca/error?id=404
ErrorDocument 403 http://james-emerson.ca/error?id=403
ErrorDocument 500 http://james-emerson.ca/error?id=500

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.james-emerson\.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://james-emerson.ca/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php

# .htaccess file for the sbfg/home.php?page= code.
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /home\.php\?page=([^\s&]*)[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ home.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And now it works as it should. Thanks everyone for helping me, not sure why was having these problems before!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `sbfg/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sbfg//home\.php\?page=([^\s&]*)[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /sbfg/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /sbfg/home.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: didn't work, I can load my home.php page, but I can't shorten the link. If I use my original .htaccess file, I can load home.php, but I can't add in the ?page=contact or short form it, into /contact for ex.

Comment: Make sure these rules are placed before your other rules.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now when I goto home.php, it goes straight to my 404 error document.

Comment: I'm still just getting redirected to the error page... Am I suppose to be adding these to the .htaccess file in the sites/external/sbfg folder or to my root?

Comment: I really have no idea what to try and do, could i maybe need to add the the subdirectories to this line: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ home.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]`.

Comment: I uploaded to 'sites/external/sbfg/.htaccess' it still didn't work. Do you know of another approach? Could this be a problem with my GoDaddy server?

Comment: It could very well be. Can you heck with them if .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled first.

Comment: I know that I can use .htaccess files. I have one in my root directory which works perfectly! Maybe it doesn't work in subdomains for another reason?

Comment: OK edited last time. Now place these 2 rules **on top of your existing rules** to see if this works. And move away your `sbfg/.htaccess` file

Comment: It didn't work but what do you mean by **now place these 2 rules on top of your existing rules** The first code box (in my question is the code of the .htaccess located in the sbfg folder; the second code located in my question is location in my root directory "/"). Maybe I have some type of other problem... Is there a way to maybe use this in my root directories code, that way it can affect all the subdirectories, not just the subdirectory that is being used for my subdomain?

Comment: What is your DOCUMENT_ROOT value? What is the full URL of a file in sbfg folder?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, I'm not sure what you mean [DOCUMENT_ROOT]? the full url? "/sites/external/sbfg/file.php"

Comment: Did you figure this out ?

Comment: yes, I posted my answer how it ended up working. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it like this, and handle the elements that have to be excluded in php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php [QSA,L]
```

It's not the easiest, but this code should work and gives complete control over when to redirect. You can easily create a table that stores nice urls to obtain the controller / action / params, maintaining old urls easier, etc.

In php, this should work from every directory, poiting to the file where the request started (home.php)

```
setup_paths();
$current_url = get_current_url(false);
$explode_uri = explode('/', $current_url);
$page_like_you_have_now = array_shift($explode_uri);

function setup_paths()
{
    define('BASE_DIR', dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    $base_url = BASE_DIR;
    if(substr($base_url, -1, 1) !== DS)
    {
        $base_url .= DS;
    }
    define('BASE_URL', str_replace('\\', '/', $base_url));
}

function get_current_url($with_base = true)
{
    $current_uri_data = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $start = strlen(BASE_DIR);
    $uri = substr($current_uri_data['path'], $start);

   //Remove possible slashes on begin, or do other corrections
    while(substr($uri, 0, 1) == '/')
    {
        $uri = substr($uri, 1); //@should 301 to correct pages afterwards..
    }

    return ($with_base ? BASE_URL : '') . $uri;
}
```

Comment: I figured out why I was getting the problem. Thanks for your help. I voted your answer up, even though it didn't really help me.